# Holley carburetor flooding my engine

Tags: carburetor

I am running a standard 600 CFM Holley carburetor on a Windsor 347 stroker engine.
After running it hard one night the engine started to flood and became very hard to start. High amount of gas is coming out of the main jet as it idles. I have checked to see if the floats needed to be adjusted by taking the side plugs out and almost no gas came out, so I’m wondering if I need to use a fuel pressure regulator. I am using a mechanical fuel pump.
Thank you

Chris

Comment: Did you ask Holly on their website? Carburetors can be complicated unless you're familiar with basic carb operation. This may as simple as the float needle valve(s) stuck open and not closing off fuel flow into the fuel chambers from debris getting into the carb. Fuel filter issue? At some point, the carb may need to be disassembled and examined to determine why it's not operating as designed.

Comment: It turned out to be a stuck needle valve thank you for your response